# How to wipe disk clean totally

Tags: grub2

I saw this has been answered before but related to windows.

I have the following on a 2009 macbook air and would like to wipe the disk and start over:

```
Minimal bash-like line editing is supported.
For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions.
Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.
Grub>
```

I typed in exit and nothing occurred. Any direction please. I do not know what else is on this particular disk and to avoid complication I just want to wipe ALL and start over newly. Please advise. Thanks. Best, Richard

Answer (score 1):

I would install a fresh copy of Ubuntu, and that will wipe the disk in the process.  That should be a sufficient "wipe" unless you are trying to hide files from a forensic investigator.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Wiping the disk is not necessary. Just boot using a LiveCD/LiveUSB and (re-)install Ubuntu. During installation, you can reformat the whole disk. That should be sufficient.

If you want to wipe the disk before reinstalling, you can write zeros across the complete disk using the LiveCD/LiveUSB, a terminal, and the `dd` command.

**Edit**

To wipe a hdd, you need to boot a Live-Image of a Linux system, eg. Ubuntu. After booting into the system, you need to open a terminal. Root privileges are required to write on hardware level to a disk, therefore you need to become root. A root shell can easily be opened by

`sudo -i`

Before you use the `dd` command, it is **absolutely necessary** to determine the correct location of your hdd. This can be done for example by `gparted`. This enables you to match the expected vs. found partitions and hdd size. **Make sure, that you are using the correct location, otherwise you will destroy the data set!!!** In the following I assume, that the hdd is located at `/dev/sda`.

To wipe the disk, you can use the command

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda`

That will write zeros on the entire disk, making it very unlikely that someone can recover the original data. Instead of `/dev/zero` you can use `/dev/urandom` to use (pseudo-)random data instead of zeros, but that will slow down the writing process dramatically! You will find often, that overwriting only one time is not sufficient to prevent recovering. I think and read that this is an urban legend (eg. [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/115573/htg-explains-why-you-only-have-to-wipe-a-disk-once-to-erase-it/)).

Hope that this description is detailed enough to wipe your disk. Last, let me put the warning here once more: **Make sure, you are using the right disk location for the `dd` command, otherwise your data will be unrecoverable destroyed!!!***

Comment: Thanks Frank. You mean just type 000000 following the grub\ command I now have? (with the install USB in). And what is "dd" exactly? I type that after? Sorry just trying to understand the sequence here. I just have the message I wrote ending in "grub" as a dos type prompt on my screen so want to understand what I type next exactly. Thanks.

Comment: Dear Richard, no... You have to boot the LiveCD.  I will add some information to my answer to illustrate the process.

Comment: Ok, thanks Frank for your full and detailed answer. I will be giving this a go at the weekend. I let you know.

Comment: Does not answer the question - the question the op is essentially asking is 'how to wipe disk from grub'